# Publish Post but don't call publish hook in foreground post creation

Tags: plugins, posts

I'm using Subscribe2 to send new post notifications to registered users on my site. I've got a couple hundred subscribers and when I add a post on the front end through a HTML page when I submit it, it takes forever to show the success message because it's sending emails in the background and won't show a success message until all of them are sent. I'm using the following code:

```
$post_status = 'publish';
$bmt_post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
    'post_content'  => $information,
    'post_status'   => $post_status,
    'post_category' => array( $cat_ids ),
    //'post_date' => $post_date,
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $bmt_post );
if($future_date_post=="yes"){
    wp_schedule_single_event( $date_time, 'publish_future_post', array( $post_id ) );
}
```

The trigger for the sending email action is in the wordpress `publish_to_publish` hook since the post is being directly saved into the database without any other statuses. The plugin has the following code to call the Publish function which sends the email:

```
foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
    add_action("{$status}_to_publish", array(&$this, 'publish'));
}
```

Is there a way to publish the post without triggering the `{$status}_to_publish` hook? If so, how could I call this hook in the background for new posts?

Possible Solution: Could I just use `wp_schedule_single_event` and make it to publish in a minute from the user hitting save so it saves it as a draft and then in the background Wordpress would publish this and trigger this Subscribe2 hook?

Pastebin of `function publish()`: http://pastebin.com/5UPUhKXw

Comment: How does Subscribe2 hook into the system? Technically, questions about third party code are off topic here for reasons evident in the question I just asked. To answer them, one would have to be familiar with the thousands of plugin and themes out there. Perhaps if you can provide more detail though,t he question can be generalized enough to come in scope for the stack.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I updated my question title and provided additional information on this.

Comment: What is the `publish()` method referenced here: `array(&$this, 'publish')` ?

Comment: @s_ha_dum This is the function in Subscribe2 to send the email notifications.

Comment: I know that. What does the code look like?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Added a Pastebin since it's a lot of code.

Comment: That is a lot of course and it is doing a lot of work. I'll think about it but I don't know if you can interior that without having the plugin.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Please see the possible solution I put in the edited question. Do you think something like that would work?

Comment: You might gutter something like that work but you probably don't want to break status hooks. I think you will have to remove the callback from the hook and add it elsewhere, but I have to think about it